# Installation error code: -15

Tags: android

При попытке установки приложения на телефон (Nexus 5) выводится сообщение "Приложение не установлено". При этом в logcat выводится следующее:

```
10-11 15:09:09.896 772-1854/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/IApp 1.7-debug.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras)} from uid 10063 on display 0
...
10-11 15:09:10.677 27832-27842/? D/DefContainer: Copying /storage/emulated/0/Download/IApp 1.7-debug.apk to base.apk
10-11 15:09:10.733 772-799/? W/PackageManager: installPackageLI
10-11 15:09:10.738 772-799/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Explicit
10-11 15:09:10.769 772-788/? I/ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{eee9fee u0 se.scmv.belarus/com.gemius.sdk.MobilePlugin}
10-11 15:09:10.829 772-799/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11603(1259KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 31% free, 34MB/50MB, paused 1.013ms total 90.194ms
10-11 15:09:10.838 28785-28785/? D/InstallAppProgress: Installation error code: -15
10-11 15:09:13.121 202-808/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
10-11 15:09:13.121 202-808/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
10-11 15:09:15.069 772-878/? D/WifiConfigStore: Retrieve network priorities after PNO.
10-11 15:09:18.503 1985-30095/? I/EventLogSendingHelper: Sending log events.
10-11 15:09:18.664 2265-2438/? I/Finsky: [151] com.google.android.finsky.k.c.a(22): Completed 0 account content syncs with 0 successful.
10-11 15:09:18.664 2265-2265/? I/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.services.e.a(5): Installation state replication succeeded.

10-11 15:09:30.081 772-878/? D/WifiConfigStore: Retrieve network priorities after PNO.
10-11 15:09:40.503 212-277/? I/ThermalEngine: TM Id 'SKIN_THERMAL_management_1' Sensor 'xo_therm_pu2' - alarm cleared 1 at 38.0 degC
10-11 15:09:40.503 212-277/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[0] to 2265600
10-11 15:09:40.504 212-277/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[1] to 2265600
10-11 15:09:40.504 212-277/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[2] to 2265600
10-11 15:09:40.504 212-277/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[3] to 2265600
10-11 15:09:40.505 212-277/? I/ThermalEngine: ACTION: LCD - Setting max LCD brightness to 255
10-11 15:09:44.569 1221-1451/? I/CastDatabase: Saving the database
10-11 15:09:44.569 1221-1451/? I/SQLiteCastStore: Saving 0 CastNetworkInfo instances, 0 CastDeviceInfo instances, 0 paired guest mode devices.
10-11 15:09:44.619 1221-1451/? E/SQLiteCastStore: End saving paired guest mode devices
10-11 15:09:45.095 772-878/? D/WifiConfigStore: Retrieve network priorities after PNO.
10-11 15:09:50.700 772-785/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 27568:com.whatsapp/u0a101 (adj 15): empty #17
10-11 15:09:50.713 772-879/? D/WifiService: Client connection lost with reason: 4
10-11 15:09:50.716 772-4497/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 27568
10-11 15:09:50.739 198-30157/? W/SocketClient: write error (Broken pipe)
10-11 15:09:50.739 198-30157/? W/DnsProxyListener: Error writing DNS result to client
10-11 15:10:00.106 772-878/? D/WifiConfigStore: Retrieve network priorities after PNO.
10-11 15:10:09.800 772-795/? I/PowerManagerService: Going to sleep due to screen timeout (uid 1000)...
10-11 15:10:09.801 772-795/? I/PowerManagerService: Sleeping (uid 1000)...
10-11 15:10:09.894 4499-4499/? W/Binder_E: type=1400 audit(0.0:3793): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[165127]" dev="sockfs" ino=165127 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
10-11 15:10:09.894 4499-4499/? W/Binder_E: type=1400 audit(0.0:3794): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[165127]" dev="sockfs" ino=165127 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
10-11 15:10:10.006 772-781/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 37814(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 31% free, 34MB/50MB, paused 955us total 111.853ms
```

В настройках в разделе "Пользователи" два аккаунта: "Вы(Owner)", который и является активным аккаунтом, и "Гость".

В чём причина ошибки и как это исправить?

Comment: Каким способом получен apk файл? На других устройствах пробовали?

Comment: @eugeneek, на других устройствах всё хорошо, приложение устанавливается. Ошибка появилась только на этом конкретном устройстве. Apk был скачан по почте и была попытка установить его через стандартный установщик приложений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, что-то не так в параметрах сборки. Вот что про эту ошибку можно найти в PackageManager:

```
/**
     * Installation return code: this is passed to the
     * {@link IPackageInstallObserver} if the new package failed because it has
     * specified that it is a test-only package and the caller has not supplied
     * the {@link #INSTALL_ALLOW_TEST} flag.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    @SystemApi
    public static final int INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY = -15;
```

Comment: Да, судя по всему, ошибка была из-за того, что в имени пакета содержалось слово "test". после изменения имени пакета ошибка пропала...